# Invalid arguments when trying to index list in simple function (R)

Tags: r, function

I have a two lists of named data in R. They are different min and max generations from energy sources.

```
mins <- bind_rows(april.mins, may.maxs)
maxs <- bind_rows(april.maxs, may.maxs)

mins <- lapply(mins, mean)
maxs <- lapply(maxs, mean)
```

I am attempting to write a function that will let me generate 600 random values from the different mins and maxs by the different named sources and then storing them.

```
vals <- function(source){
  runif(600, min = mins$source, max = max$source) 
   }
```

When I individually run this, I am able to generate the random values. For ex:

```
runif(600, min = mins$biogas, max = maxs$biogas)
```

However, as the function, it returns an "invalid arguments" error.

```
vals(geothermal)
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: note on first line: should be mins <- bind_rows(april.mins, may.>mins<)

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names

may want to try it using bracket subsetting

vals <- function(source){
  runif(600, min = mins[source], max = max[source]) 
   }

Comment: accessing via brackets produces same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
minss = data.frame(biogas=5)

maxss = data.frame(biogas=10)

vals <- function(source){
  runif(600, min = minss[[source]], max = maxss[[source]]) 
}

vals('biogas')
```